# Onclick event not being applied to every button on page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a for each loop in my HTML code which will display multiple buttons on the page. I have used JavaScript so that whenever a button gets clicked the text color and background should change. However, this seems to only get applied to the first button and not any which come after.

HTML:

```
<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn" onclick="status(event)">
```

JavaScript:

```
function status() {
    if(event.target == document.getElementById("btn")) {
        document.getElementById("btn").value = "Copied to clipboard";
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("btn").style.color = 'white';
        document.getElementById("btn").style.background = 'gray';

    }
}
```

I am fairly new with JavaScript so I am not sure if there is something I am missing in the JavaScript portion of the code or if it's the loop that is causing this to not work. I need to use a loop since I am also displaying other information which requires a loop.

Comment: What's your full HTML? (looks like you might have duplicate IDs, which is invalid)

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If your `for each loop` duplicates the `button` in your example then you should know that you shouldn't duplicate `id`'s. ID's are supposed to be unique so if you have multiple `id="btn"` then that will be your problem. If you plan to set `onclick` attribute on all buttons you could have it set to `onclick="status()";` and use `this.value / this.disabled` if your function.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thanks so much for replying so quickly! I am not able to post the entire HTML since this is a project (but don't worry I am not being lazy and not doing the work myself. I have tried searching multiple times before posting a question on here.) But to sum it up for you the main parts of the HTML are the for-each loop which displays some information I am getting from a database and then each time it iterates through the loop it displays a button.

Comment: You don't need to post all of it, just enough to reproduce the problem - see [MCVE]. If you have duplicate IDs, then that's the problem - your HTML is invalid.

Comment: @NewToJS ah you are so right!! That is defined the problem!! Do you have any suggestions on how I should modify it then? Because I do need to have a button displayed everytime it goes through the loop and it should be able to have the onlick applied to it.

Comment: @daisygal classes don't need to be unique, so you can make all the classes of your button `btn` so you can then get all the buttons with this class using `document.getElementsByClassName('btn');`. However, I suggest that you use the `this` keyword to reference the button which you clicked on.

Comment: @daisygal maybe this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/noh05w38/) could be of some help. Using this method you won't need to set any `id`'s so that will remove the problem of creating duplicates.

Comment: @NewToJS thanks so much for the demo! That really clears things up. I'm still confused on how I can change the text, color, and background color when the button is clicked since I am used to using the `document.getElementsById('...');` to change the button

Comment: @daisygal That is simple enough to do. You would do exactly the same thing as you would if you were using `document.getElementById()` as the selector to change things but using `e.target` as the selector. Please take a look at this second [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/noh05w38/3/) I have created for you.

Comment: @NewToJS Oh gotcha!! wow, that is so much easier than I thought! Thank you so much for your help!!! You are awesome!!! This worked!

Comment: @daisygal You are very welcome. Here to help :) If you have any questions about the source code in the demos I have provided please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue seems to be that you are using the same `id` on multiple elements. I suggest that you remove these `id`s.

Instead, I think you would benefit by using the `this` keyword. You can use `this` by passing it into your `status` function in the `onclick` event listener:

`onclick="status(this)"`

Now, the passed in variable `clickedBtn` is referencing the button which you clicked, and so you can change its properties accordingly.

Take a look at the snippet below to get a better understanding:

```js
function status(clickedBtn) {
  clickedBtn.value = "Copied to clipboard";
  clickedBtn.disabled = true;
  clickedBtn.style.color = 'white';
  clickedBtn.style.background = 'gray';
}
```

```html
<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn" onclick="status(this)">
<br />

<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn" onclick="status(this)">
<br />

<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn" onclick="status(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use the `addEventListener` in javascript for security reasons. and also you are iterating the button so you need to use class for it not id coz id is unique, it will return you an error in background. so i edit your code. and this works for me.

**HTML**

```
<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn">
<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn">
<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn">
<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn">
<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn">
```

**Javascript**

```
(function() {
  const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("big-button")

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.value = "Copied to clipboard"
      this.disabled = true
      this.style.color = "white"
      this.style.background = "gray"
    })
  })
})()
```

Comment: This is a great example but keep in mind this will have to be executed after the *"for each loop"* which creates the `button`s since they are dynamically created.

Comment: Yes this still works even though the button are dynamically created  as long as you declared the class coz the event listener will listen the class.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function status() {
        event.target.value = "Copied to clipboard";
        event.target.disabled = true;
        event.target.style.color = 'white';
        event.target.style.background = 'gray';
}
```

```html
<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn" onclick="status(event)">
<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn" onclick="status(event)">
<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn" onclick="status(event)">
<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Apply this promotion" id="btn" onclick="status(event)">
```

The status function always checks for the same button ID: "btn". Hence it alters the style of the same button element. Modify your function to the below:

```
function status() {
    event.target.value = "Copied to clipboard";
    event.target.disabled = true;
    event.target.style.color = 'white';
    event.target.style.background = 'gray';
}
```

Now, try with the same HTML. The above function alters the style of the clicked element only.